# As a windows user I get No such File or Directory error in gitlab when I run the pipeline , how can I configure the directory for deploying

Tags: linux, windows, gitlab, cicd

The error message I get when I run the pipeline is :

```
$ scp -r music ec2-user@1xxxxxxxx:"C:\Users\dddd\OneDrive\Belgeler"
$ ssh ec2-user@1xxxxxxxx  "cd /Users/dddd/OneDrive/Belgeler/music && docker compose up -d"

bash: line 0: cd: /c/Users/dddd/OneDrive/Belgeler/music: No such file or directory
```

I also try these paths too :

```
mnt/c/Users/dddd/OneDrive/Belgeler/music
C:\Users\dddd\OneDrive\Belgeler\music
```

I want to make ci/cd configuration

Answer (score 0):

I have handled this situation when I try to find the exact location from the aws machine that I use instead of ubuntu or gitbash terminal in my computer.